# What does MAX do in Objec-C/cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Example:

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int x = MAX(position.x, winSize.width /2);
    int y = MAX(position.y, winSize.height /2);
    x = MIN(x, (_tileMap.mapSize.width * _tileMap.tileSize.width)
            - winSize.width /2);
    y = MIN(y, (_tileMap.mapSize.height *_tileMap.tileSize.height)
            -winSize.height/2);
    CGPoint actualPosition = ccp(x, y);

    CGPoint centerOfView = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    self.position = centerOfView;
```

Note the MAX which is defined in NSObject. I am still hazy what it does. I tried looking it up in the text documentation but got no relevant result.

Similarly, does ccp just take two coordinates and save them into one point?

E.G.

```
CGPoint centerOfView = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's a *macro* that takes two expressions, evaluates them, and returns the larger value of the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MAX simply returns the MAX value of the items in parenthesis. For example, MAX(5,3) would return 5.

If x=1 and y=10, then MAX(y,x) would return y.

`ccp` is a wrapper around `CGPointMake` and it simply creates a CGPoint, which is made up of two values, x and y, to create a 2D coordinate. Look up `CGPointMake` as that is exactly what `ccp` is.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode hold Command and click the function for its definition.

```
#define MAX(A,B)({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __b : __a; })
```

ccp is defined as

```
#define ccp(__X__,__Y__) CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__)
```

To see the file where it's all defined hold command and click on the function. Xcode will loop up the symbol.